# Replace NA with a value that is row and column specific

Tags: r, loops, replace, data.table, na

A lot comes together in this question. First off all I would like to segment the data by column c. The subsets are given by the factor c: the levels are 1 to 4. So 4 distinct segments.
Next I have two columns. Column a and b.
I would like to replace the NA's with the maximum value of each segment specific column. So for example, NA at row 3 and column 'a', this would be 30. (b,3) would be 80, (b,8) would be 50 and (a, 5) would be 80.

I have created the code below that does the job, but now I need to make it automatic (like a for loop) for all segments and columns. How could I do this?

```
a <- c(10,NA,30,40,NA,60,70,80,90,90,80,90,10,40)
b <- c(80,70,NA,50,40,30,20,NA,0,0,10,69, 40, 90)
c <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)


      a  b c
 1:  10 80 1
 2:  NA 70 1
 3:  30 NA 1
 4:  40 50 2
 5:  NA 40 2
 6:  60 30 2
 7:  70 20 2
 8:  80 NA 2
 9:  90  0 3
 10: 90  0 3
 11: 80 10 3
 12: 90 69 4
 13: 10 40 4
 14: 40 90 4


mytable <- data.table(a,b,c)

mytable[which(is.na(mytable[c == 1][,1, with = FALSE]) == TRUE),1] <- max(mytable[c==1,1], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Unfortunately, this try results in an error:

```
for(i in unique(mytable$c)){
  for(j in unique(c(1:2))){
    mytable[which(is.na(mytable[c == i][,j, with = FALSE]) == TRUE),j, with = FALSE] <- max(mytable[c==i][,j, with = FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, which(is.na(mytable[c == i][, j, with = FALSE]) ==  : 
  unused argument (with = FALSE)

Surprisingly, this results in an error as well:

```
for(i in unique(mytable$c)){
  for(j in unique(c(1:2))){
    mytable[which(is.na(mytable[c == i][,j]) == TRUE),j] <- max(mytable[c==i,j], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Error in `[.data.table`(mytable, c == i, j) : 
      j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name  'j' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[,..j] or DT[,j,with=FALSE]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.

Comment: Using `dplyr` : `mytable %>% group_by(c) %>% mutate(a = ifelse(is.na(a),max(a,na.rm=TRUE),a), b = ifelse(is.na(b),max(b,na.rm=TRUE),b))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library("data.table")

mytable <- data.table(
a=c(10,NA,30,40,NA,60,70,80,90,90,80,90,10,40),
b=c(80,70,NA,50,40,30,20,NA,0,0,10,69, 40, 90),
c=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4))

foo <- function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- max(x, na.rm=TRUE); x }

mytable[, .(A=foo(a), B=foo(b)), by=c]
```

result:

```
> mytable[, .(A=foo(a), B=foo(b)), by=c]
#    c  A  B
# 1: 1 10 80
# 2: 1 30 70
# 3: 1 30 80
# 4: 2 40 50
# 5: 2 80 40
# 6: 2 60 30
# 7: 2 70 20
# 8: 2 80 50
# 9: 3 90  0
#10: 3 90  0
#11: 3 80 10
#12: 4 90 69
#13: 4 10 40
#14: 4 40 90
```

or for direct substitution of `a` and `b`:

```
mytable[, `:=`(a=foo(a), b=foo(b)), by=c] # or
mytable[, c("a", "b") := (lapply(.SD, foo)), by = c]  # from @Sotos
```

or the safer variant (tnx to @Frank for the remark):

```
cols <- c("a", "b")
mytable[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, foo), by=c, .SDcols=cols]
```

Comment: or `dt[, lapply(.SD, foo), by = c]`

Comment: this doesn't modify `mytable` and only prints the replaced values

Comment: @manotheshark I edited my answer.

Comment: Very impressive and efficient! Use of data table and avoidance of for loops addresses the problem directly. Thank you. I used: mytable <- mytable[, .(a=foo(a), b=foo(b)), by=c] as solution

Answer (score 2):

Using data.table

```
library(data.table)
mytable[, a := ifelse(is.na(a), max(a, na.rm = TRUE), a), by = c]
mytable[, b := ifelse(is.na(b), max(b, na.rm = TRUE), b), by = c]
```

Or in a single command

```
mytable[, c("a", "b") := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), max(x, na.rm = TRUE), x)), .SDcols = c("a", "b"), by = c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ddply()` from package `plyr`:

```
df<-data.frame(a,b,c=as.factor(c))
library(plyr)
df2<-ddply(df, .(c), transform, a=ifelse(is.na(a), max(a, na.rm=T),a), 
           b=ifelse(is.na(b), max(b, na.rm=T),b))
```